# Display All Activities, Fragments in one Frame Layout using Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-framelayout

I am using `DrawerLayout` for `Slider Menu` and it is main Activity. It contains `Frame Layout`.
Main page is Home which will be open in `Frame Layout` and It is `Fragment`. It is working fine. Now, Home contains 2 buttons and I am opening different `Activity` based on which `Button` is clicked.
It opens new `Activity` but I want to open it in same Frame Layout in which Home is there, so that I can extend Slider menus in All `Activity`.
How to implement this ?
**home.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/lightgray"
    android:scrollbars="none" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llPractice"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/home_list_selector"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:src="@drawable/practice" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="3dip" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="@string/practice"
                    android:textColor="@color/dark_black"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:typeface="sans" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                    android:src="@drawable/arrow" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llStudy"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/home_list_selector"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:src="@drawable/study" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="3dip" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="@string/study"
                    android:textColor="@color/dark_black"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:typeface="sans" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                    android:src="@drawable/arrow" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

**Home.java :**

```
public class Home extends Fragment {

    View llPractice;
    View llStudy;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);

        llPractice = rootView.findViewById(R.id.llPractice);
        llStudy = rootView.findViewById(R.id.llStudy);
        llTest = rootView.findViewById(R.id.llTest);
        llGKQuiz = rootView.findViewById(R.id.llGKQuiz);

        llPractice.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent openRandomQuestion = new Intent(getActivity(),
                        Practice.class);
                startActivity(openRandomQuestion);
            }
        });

        llStudy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
                fm.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.frame_container, new Study()).commit();
            }
        });

        llTest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent openRandomQuestion = new Intent(getActivity(),
                    Test.class);
                startActivity(openRandomQuestion);
            }
        });


        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you opening activity..try using `FragmentActivity`..

Comment: Will it open in Frame Layout directly ???

Comment: Do one thing : **load the fragment in Framelayout only on the click of the button**.. The other option is to create on BaseActivity which extends SliderFragemetActivtiy and then Extend  this `BaseActivity` in all the activitirs where you want the slider..

Comment: @SweetWisherツ, i am learner so don't have that much idea. Can you tell me in details ?

Comment: wait I'll show you...

Comment: try to implement fragment activity and no need to create ant base activity.

Comment: @DevCarlsberg, can u tell me in detail ?

Comment: ahhh,you can replace only fragment in your framne layout and not the activities.just take  a single activity and e xtend it with a fragmentacivity. and implement drawer.its very simple.better to try with fragments only.

Answer (score 0):

## The solution is :

To Create a `BaseActivity` and then Extend this BaseActivity in all the activities  :

**Sample Code :**

```
        public class BaseActivity extends Activity {
        
            // Access you navaigation drawer here
        
        
            private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
            private ListView mDrawerList;
        
        
         }
    
    public class YourActivity extends BaseActivity {


    }
```

And Once have a [look here](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/) and [here too](http://www.tutecentral.com/android-custom-navigation-drawer/) to create a working demo with `DrawerLayout`.